# Get the document with the maximum value of a field when all documents are referenced through a foreign key in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have 2 collections, one for experiments containing experiment name and run number (an experiment can be run multiple times), and one for some metrics/values logged for a specific experiment-run pair.

```
experiments: {
   experiment_name: str
   run: int
}
```

```
metrics: {
   experiment: experiments.ID
   metric_name: str
   metric_value: float
```

What I would like is, for a given value of `metric_name`, find the maximum value of `run` from the referenced `experiment` that logged the `metric_name`.

One way I can gather is to first get all documents in `metrics` that contain the specific `metric_name`. Then iterate through the referenced `experiments.ID`s, materialize the corresponding list of `experiments` documents, and find the maximum value of `run`.

But this seems tedious and inelegant (and slow). Is there a faster way, or some built-in foreign key pattern reference I can use? (Also, would appreciate any solutions/links in `pymongo` specifically, if possible).

Answer (score 0):

You could let the MongoDB server do the tedious work for you doing something like this.

N.B.:  The pipeline should be directly usable by `pymongo`.

```js
db.metrics.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "metric_name": your_metric_name
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "experiments",
      "localField": "experiment",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "experiment"
    }
  },
  {"$unwind": "$experiment"},
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$experiment._id",
      "metric_name": {"$first": "$metric_name"},
      "experiment_name": {"$first": "$experiment.experiment_name"},
      "max_run": {"$max": "$experiment.run"}
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/umguJ5ci3qN) with a bit of nonsensical data.